# Slick vertical slider issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slider, slick.js

I'm trying to implement a slick vertical slider like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO6BR.png)

And the closer I could get so far is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYqwM.png)

The setting I'm currently using are these:

```
    this.settings = {
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  arrows: true,
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  infinite: true
};
```

}

If I change the variable slidesToShow to 1, the arrows come back again but then I need to change the vertical padding to 100% so I can see all the slides.

Like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRnpL.png)

Is there any simpler way to show all the 4 items and make them scrollable with arrows?

Comment: Hello Luis, could you provide a link to a fiddle with your code so we can look into it

Comment: It's hard to reproduce it since I'm using React.js and Fiddle is giving me the following error "Unclosed regular expression". I will build a carousel from scratch, it might be the fastest solution

Answer (score 1):

**
Hope this will help you

**

```js
const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    adaptiveHeight:true,
    variableHeight:false
  };


<Slider
            {...settings}
            afterChange={(currentSlide) => {
              setSlide(currentSlide + 1);
            }}
          >
            {orgData?.map((slider, i) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <div className="organization-main-section" key={i}>
                    <div className="organization-left-content">
                      <div className="organization-section-content">
                        <h2>{slider?.Heading}</h2>
                        <p className='organization-desc'>{slider?.Description}</p>
                        <ul>
                          {slider?.List?.map((li, i) => {
                            return (
                              <>
                                <li key={i}>{li?.List}</li>
                              </>
                            );
                          })}
                        </ul>
                        <Link to={slider?.MeetneedBtn?.url}>{slider?.MeetneedBtn?.text}</Link>
                        <div className="quote-box">
                          <div className="quote-section">
                            <img src={quoteimg1} alt="quote" />
                            <p>{slider?.Quates?.Quates}</p>
                            <img src={quoteimg2} alt="quote" />
                          </div>
                          <img
                            src={slider?.Quates?.Logo[0]?.url}
                            alt={slider?.Quates?.Logo[0]?.name}
                          />
                          <p>{slider?.Quates?.About}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="organization-right-content">
                      <div className="organization-section-cover">
                        <img src={slider?.Img?.url} alt="cover" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </>
              );
            })}

          </Slider>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).